# Android How to keep non chromecast devices from showing up in the selection list

Tags: android, chromecast

Im adding chromecast support into an app Im working on and Ive noticed that I see every test device that streams video including an xbox one and numerous rokus, smart tv's, and apple tv's that we develop on. Now I cant cast to them directly so I was wondering two things.

First can I use the mediarouter api's on android to cast to these devices and second how can I keep them from showing up in the device selection list.

EDIT: This is how I set up my MediaRouteSelector

```
mMediaRouter = MediaRouter.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
        mediaRouteSelector = new MediaRouteSelector.Builder()
        .addControlCategory(CastMediaControlIntent.categoryForCast(Config.ChromecastRecieverID))
        .addControlCategory(MediaControlIntent.CATEGORY_LIVE_AUDIO)
            .addControlCategory(MediaControlIntent.CATEGORY_LIVE_VIDEO)
            .addControlCategory(MediaControlIntent.CATEGORY_REMOTE_PLAYBACK)
        .build();

MenuItem mediaRouteMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.media_route_menu_item);
MediaRouteActionProvider mediaRouteActionProvider = 
(MediaRouteActionProvider) MenuItemCompat.getActionProvider(mediaRouteMenuItem);

if(mediaRouteActionProvider==null){
    mediaRouteActionProvider  = new  MediaRouteActionProvider(this);
    MenuItemCompat.setActionProvider(mediaRouteMenuItem, mediaRouteActionProvider);
            }
mediaRouteActionProvider.setRouteSelector(this.mediaRouteSelector);
mediaRouteActionProvider.setDialogFactory(new MediaRouteDialogFactory() {
    @Override
    public MediaRouteControllerDialogFragment onCreateControllerDialogFragment() {
           return new MediaRouteControllerDialogFragment() {
                  @Override
                  public MediaRouteControllerDialog onCreateControllerDialog(
                                    Context context, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                                MediaRouteControllerDialog mControllerDialog = new MediaRouteControllerDialog(BaseActivity.this);
                                return mControllerDialog;
                            }
                        };
                    }
                });
```

Comment: "Ive noticed that I see every test device that streams video" -- see them where?

Comment: In the device selection dialog that displays when I push the chromecast button from the menu

Comment: Also that this only happens on android devices. I never see any non chromecast devices show up in the list in the ios version of the app we are working on

Comment: How are you setting up your `MediaRouteSelector`?

Comment: Ive added how Im using it as of now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now I cant cast to them directly

Your code is not written to *only* "cast". Hence, you will pick up:

- Anything that is paired with your device that provides a live audio route, like Bluetooth speakers
- Anything that is connected with your device that provides a live video route, like Miracast
- Anything that an app on your device publishes a `MediaRouteProvider` for that implements the `RemotePlaybackClient` protocol (basically, Chromecast minus the more advanced receiver customization options)

> First can I use the mediarouter api's on android to cast to these devices

That depends on your use of the verb "cast". All are available media routes, whether for live audio, live video, standard Android remote playback, or Chromecast-specific remote playback.

> how can I keep them from showing up in the device selection list

If you do not want to be delivering content to those things, remove the categories from your `MediaRouteSelector`.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. I wasnt aware that the extra .addControlCategory calls I added would allow me to see all the extra devices in the list.